# `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: ` when button pressed

Tags: android, gradle, .so

I'm having an error when im clicking a button to print. this is the error that logged:
    `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: com.jti.ph.pos_app.Interface.PrinterInterface.open:()`

I have put the `*.so` to `jniLibs` folder manually and I noticed the `*.so` file has turned red.

I also add an code on `build.gradle(Module:app)`

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['jniLibs']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src/main/aidl']
    }
}
```

this is the image:

[image]

This is the detailed logs:
[image]

need your help on this.

Answer (score 0):

**In a nutshell your libraries are not loading**

you may try on of the following :

1. Copy the *.so files to jniLibs.
2. add the libraries to the build path.
3. If you are running in simulator, then make sure that you have specified the correct architecture.

   > Run -> Run Configurations -> Target (you may need to add the required simulator using Window -> Android Virtual Device Manager).

Comment: i have tried to drag the *.so files and the files are green now but the logs is still the same

Comment: `FATAL EXCEPTION: 
                                                                       Process: 
                                                                       java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: com.jti.ph.pos_app.Interface.PrinterInterface.open:()I
                                                                           at com.jti.ph.pos_app.Interface.PrinterInterface.open(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.jti.ph.pos_app.Fragments.Issue_Ticket$21.run(Issue_Ticket.java:1127)`